# Java Copy Stream using Buffers with same size

Tags: java, stream

With the following logic used to copy a file using input/output streams.  Is there truly a benefit of using the Bufferred Streams since it is using a byte buffer of the same size?

```
int bufferSize = getDefaultBufferSize();
input = new BufferedInputStream(in, bufferSize);
output = new BufferedOutputStream(out, bufferSize);
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int numBytes = 0;
long totalBytes = 0L;
while ((numBytes = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
    totalBytes += numBytes;
}
output.flush();
```

Comment: Same size to what? What are you really comparing here? Whether you want to use `in` and `out` directly?

Comment: The size is the same for input stream/output stream/buffer.  However I do not believe the streams are necessary and provide any performance increase because the array buffer is used when reading and writing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedInputStream` gives you no benefit at all here.

With `BufferedOutputStream` it's not so clear. The underlying output device may support efficient transfer of blocks that are larger than the blocks that the input stream returns, so removing `BufferedOutputStream` *may* mean you'll make a larger number of smaller writes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought.  Wouldn't the BufferredOutputStream not have any benefit in this scenario as well?  Since the array buffer is same size and we are writing using the buffer the underlying output device issue would apply with or without the usage of the BufferredOutputStream no?

Comment: Reading from the input stream, you'll get blocks of data in sizes determined by the input device. Let's say it's typically 1kB. Let's say `bufferSize` is 4kB. Without buffered output you'll write a 1kB block to the output device in every run of the loop. With buffered output, you'll write 4kB once every 4 runs. Whether that is a meaningful difference is hard to say